# How to use PersonMailingCountry in sharing rules?

Tags: apex, sharing, person-accounts, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing

I have a requirement where I need to create a sharing rule on person accounts based on the person mailing country field (part of `PersonMailingAddress` field). When I run a soql query I can find the results but when I try to create a sharing rule I can't see person related address fields for criteria based sharing. Person Accounts is enabled for my org and I have selected a person account record type for the first criteria.
For example, if I run the following SOQL :

```
Select Id, PersonMailingCountry from Account where PersonMailingCountry='India'
```

It shows me results. However when I try to find `PersonMailingCountry` in Account sharing rules, it doesn't appear.

Can it be done via sharing rules? Or the only way to do is by apex managed sharing?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.